# MongoDB : Sorting Data when using DBcollection find

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to return the results from the find query with the help of sortaing based on lastUpdated field .

Currently i have seen two ways

**First Approach**

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("updated_at","-1");
query.put(MONGO_ATTR_SYMBOL, "" + symbol);
DBCursor cursor = DBcollection.find(query).sort(query);
```

**Second Approach**

```
DBCursor cursor = DBcollection.find(query,new BasicDBObject("sort", new BasicDBObject("lastUpdated ", -1)));
```

What is the best option to work with any ideas ??

Answer (score 12):

If you take a look at Java Driver API, the method [find](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#find%28com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject%29%20find) expects two parameters, the query and the fields that will be returned.

Once you want to sort the results, use the traditional find method and sort the DBCursor.

```
DBCursor cursor = DBCollection.find(query);
cursor.sort(new BasicDBObject("lastUpdated ", -1));
```

Remember, the DBCursor object do a lazy fetch to database, so you can use sort, limit or skip without overheads.